# How to extract specific text in html code with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a website where I want to extract some data from. I want to extract the 8a on the second line (a-element) with JSoup. I can not use Regex because sometimes 8a is just 2 or 7c+ and these same values can be in the text in between the a tags as well. Ideas?

```
<div class="vsr"> 
 <a href="/91.1/303535.html">L'Américain (intégral)</a> 8a 
 <span class="ag">7c+</span> 
 <em>Tony Fouchereau</em> 
 <span class="btype">traversée d-g, surplomb, départ assis</span> 
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup css selectors to extract specific information.

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

```
@Test
public void extract8a() {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"vsr\"> \n" +
            " <a href=\"/91.1/303535.html\">L'Américain (intégral)</a> 8a \n" +
            " <span class=\"ag\">7c+</span> \n" +
            " <em>Tony Fouchereau</em> \n" +
            " <span class=\"btype\">traversée d-g, surplomb, départ assis</span> \n" +
            " <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-camera\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span> \n" +
            " <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-film\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span> \n" +
            "</div>");
    System.out.println(doc.select("div.vsr").first().ownText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a whole new world of web scraping just opened

Comment: If you're using recent Jsoup version you can use `doc.selectFirst("div.vsr")` instead of `doc.select("div.vsr").first()`.